# Fastest algorithm to merge 2 arrays such that elements are interlocked at even intervals

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

**Requirements:**

- Integer operations only (no floats)
- Elements are interlocked at intervals as evenly as possible

**Note:**

- "Intervals as evenly as possible" can be defined as having each length of intervals as close to one value as possible.
- Micro-optimizations are welcome and desired.

**Example inputs and outputs:**

```
//Inputs
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 10, 20, 30, 40 ]

//Correct output
[ 1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30, 4, 5, 40, 6, 7]

//Wrong output ([5, 6, 7] is not an optimal interval)
[ 1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30, 4, 40, 5, 6, 7]
```

-

```
//Inputs
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[ 2, 2, 2 ]

//Correct output
[ 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1]

//Wrong output (last [1] is not an optimal interval)
[ 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1]
```

Comment: First, pick one language. Second, try something yourself. Third, if *micro-optimizations are welcome and desired* then you should probably explain *why* and whether you want to optimize for size, memory usage or performance. Or maybe re-think your approach and [**Write Dumb Code**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 1st: Okay. 2nd: I did, but lets pretend this question is still valid. 3rd: No, this is a general optimization request, nothing specific.

Comment: Any [good line drawing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) will do this.

Comment: @user3386109 Yup, I was using Bresenham but not sure if that was the fastest. I guess I'll post my answer and see if people have faster implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own implementation with as much optimization as I can think of for a managed language. In C++, it may be faster to use a triple XOR swap for the array pointers, but I'm not sure. It may be necessary to look at the JITed assembly to further optimize this particular code.

In the meantime, let's see if other people have better algorithms.

```
int[] InterlockMerge(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    var longSet = a1;
    var shortSet = a2;

    //Swap if a2 is longer
    if (a1.Length < a2.Length){
        longSet = a2;
        shortSet = a1;
    }

    var ll = longSet.Length;
    var ls = shortSet.Length;
    var totalLength = ll + ls;
    int[] res = new int[totalLength];                   //The resulting set

    int l = ll / (ls + 1);                              //Initial testing ratio (an int)
    int li = 0;                                         //index for longSet
    int si = 0;                                         //index for shortSet
    for (int i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) {
        if (l > 0) {
            res[i] = longSet[li++];
            l--;
            continue;
        }
        res[i] = shortSet[si++];
        l = (ll - li) / (ls - si + 1);                  //Recalculate the testing ratio
    }
    return res;
}
```